# serializeArray() to add additional info on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using serializeArray) to submit form data + some additional info. But for some reason this doesn't work.

```
$("#submitBtn").submit(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var info = $(this).serializeArray();
    info.push({
      name: 'teacherName', value: $('#tNm').text(),
      name: 'teacherSubject', value: $('#tSj').text()
    });
    var url = "data.php";
    $.post(url, info, function(response){ ... }
    return false;
});
```

How do I send for data + additional info on submit?

Comment: you are pushing an object that has repeating keys `name` and `value` into `info`

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the objects separately

```
info.push({name: 'teacherName', value: $('#tNm').text()});
info.push({name: 'teacherSubject', value: $('#tSj').text()});
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8g02fjx/) I made